# PHP, DB connection in Function. Is Separate Connection Mandatory?

Tags: php, function, postgresql, connection

I am using in my PHP file a function which is defines inside the PHP file. He structure of the code is like below

//--- db connection

```
$dbconn = pg_connect(...
```

// function definition

```
function myfunction(){
  $f_stmt = '.....'
  $f_result = pg_query_params($dbconn,$f_stmt, ....
  $val = pg_fetch_result($f_result, 'COL_VAL');
  return $val;
}
```

//---- general logic

```
  $stmt = '....'
  $result = pg_query_params($dbconn,$stmt, ....

   while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo myfunction()
   }
```

When I am trying to use the same connection in the function $dbconn like tje sample above I am receiving a connection error. When I create a new connection $dbconn2 inside the function for its own usage it works. If this is the solution isn't it bad for the performance? or is there a proper way?

Comment: You need to make the `$dbconn` accessible inside the function `global $dbconn;` at the top of the function (before other code) will do the trick

Comment: Otherwise you can put the var as a parameter of the function and pass the data each time you call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your connection variable `$dbconn` to global variable ,

```
function myfunction(){
  global $dbconn;
  $f_stmt = '.....'
  $f_result = pg_query_params($dbconn,$f_stmt, ....
  $val = pg_fetch_result($f_result, 'COL_VAL');
  return $val;
}
```